# SQL Server add leading zero to single digit month

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I'm trying to add a leading zero to months where there is only a single digit (everything before October).  Here's my code:

```
with tab1 as (
    select month(CommitDate) monCommDt
            , year(CommitDate) yrCommDt
    from myTable

)

select CASE WHEN LEN(monCommDt) = 1
            THEN CONCAT('0', monCommDt)
            ELSE monCommDt
            END lzCommDt
        , yrCommDt
        , LEN(monCommDt) lenCommDt
from tab1
```

Here's the output:

```
lzCommDt    yrCommDt    lenCommDt
7   2013    1
7   2013    1
7   2013    1
7   2013    1
```

Any idea why the leading 0 isn't being added?

Answer (score 8):

The reason why the leading 0 is not added is because the result of your `CASE` expression is converted back to `INT`. Remember when using a `CASE` expression, if the datatype of all the results is not the same, they are converted to the one with the higher [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), in this case, an `INT`. You should `CAST` your results to `VARCHAR` to achieve the desired result:

```
CASE 
    WHEN LEN(monCommDt) = 1
        THEN CONCAT('0', CAST(monCommDt AS VARCHAR(2)))
    ELSE 
        CAST(monCommDt AS VARCHAR(2))
END lzCommDt
```

Another solution is to pad the result by using `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(monCommDt AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

use Right function:

```
select Right('0' + cast(month(CommitDate) as varchar), 2) monCommDt
      , year(CommitDate) yrCommDt
from myTable
```